# Compressing a PNG data url in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I've got a data URL like this:

`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA...`

They tend to be very long, what is the best way to compress it in Express/Node?

Comment: Would it help to convert it to a byte array? Or blob?

Comment: Everything from the `iVBOR...` part until the end is base64.  So converting that back to binary will shave off 25% from the original string length. PNG isn't going to compress much more after that.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: If you're keeping it as a data URL and not rebuilding the image from scratch, there's nothing you can really do.  But, you could go back to the source and reduce the size of the original image (with greater lossy compression) back at the source or reduce the number of pixels.  If you have this in nodejs, you could decode, decompress, resample, recompress, reencode the image to make it lower quality or reduced resolution.

Comment: In case you didn't realize, data URLs like this contain the entire data for the image, thus why they are not small.

Comment: Should have mentioned that I am ok with lossy compression! As long as I have control of the file size that comes out of it, for example that I can set the compression to strictly compress to ~around~ 100KB